# Forcing a Power BI Column chart to only display every Nth X Axis Label

Tags: powerbi, time-series, x-axis

I am trying to create a set of small column / line charts showing half-hourly energy consumption data for a data with the time as the X axis.   When I use a simple numeric value for the Period Number (1-48) as the X axis it will happily only display 0, 20 and 40th value on the Axis labels as in the 1st image.

[Chart with HH Number as X axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xukqR.png)

But I want the times to be displayed in the same way showing, for example 00:00, 04:00, 08:00 12:00 etc which is every 8th half-hourly time period.

When I change the z axis to the Time field it does 2 things which I want to avoid:

1. It includes every time and I can't find a way to only display every 8th time - so the chart width is then defined by the minimum font size of the labels (8) and it widens the chart requiring the user to use a scroll bar (this is the primary reason I want to limit the X axis labels to every 8th value).
2. It changes the sort of the data from the Period Number (chronological) to the Y Axis Value in descending order which I definitely don't want.

These features can be seen in action on the second image attached.
[Chart with Time as X Axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LsWQ.png)

I have tried creating a Text column which only includes every 4th or 8th Time and is blank for the rest, but when I use that as the X axis it aggregates all the Y values for the Blank periods.  I feel like I want it to use the original time period as the x axis BUT display the x axis labels using a different column but can't find how to do this either.